# PHP: Rewriting switch as class

Tags: php, arrays, oop

So, I have a switch statement inside a foreach loop that checks the value of a field in the array and uses the value to build a named array and email address variable for each unique value. Question is below example code.

As an example, if the values are foo, bar, and foobar, then the following occurs:

```
switch($value['value']) {
    case 'foo':
        if(!isset($foo)){
            $foo = array();
        }
        if(!isset($email_foo)){
            $email_foo = convert_to_email($value['value']);
        }
        array_push($foo, $value);
    break;
    case 'bar':
        if(!isset($bar)){
            $bar = array();
        }
        if(!isset($email_bar)){
            $email_bar = convert_to_email($value['value']);
        }
        array_push($bar, $value);
    break;
    case 'foobar':
        if(!isset($foobar)){
            $foobar = array();
        }
        if(!isset($email_foobar)){
            $email_foobar = convert_to_email($value['value']);
        }
        array_push($foobar, $value);
    break;
    default:
        if(!isset($default)){
            $default = array();
        }
        if(!isset($email_default)){
            $email_default = 'this@isemail.com';
        }
        array_push($default, $value);
}
```

Resulting in 4 different email addresses:

```
$email_foo     = 'foo@isemail.com';
$email_bar     = 'bar@isemail.com';
$email_foobar  = 'foobar@isemail.com';
$email_default = 'default@isemail.com';
```

and 4 different arrays of data:

```
$foo = array(
    0 => array(
        'value' => 'F Oo',
        'name' => 'Janet',
        'age' => 23
        ),
    1 => array(
        'value' => 'F Oo',
        'name' => 'Doug',
        'age' => 42
        )
    )

$bar = array(
    0 => array(
        'value' => 'B Ar',
        'name' => 'James',
        'age' => 23
        ),
    1 => array(
        'value' => 'B Ar',
        'name' => 'Donald',
        'age' => 42
        )
    )
```

etc...

**So, here is the question:**
Is it possible to write a class that can be used to create all of the named arrays and email variables? Sort of something like this:

```
class Account_Manager_Build
{
public function __construct()
{
    if(!isset($this)){
        $this = array();
    }
    if(!isset("email_$this")){
        "email_$this" = convert_to_email($this->value['value']);
    }
    array_push($this, $this->value);
}
}
```

For testing purposes, here is the function convert_to_email that is used throughout the examples:

```
function convert_to_email($input){
$returned = strtolower(substr($input, 0, 1)).strtolower(end(str_word_count($input, 2))).'@ismail.com';
return $returned;
}
```

Comment: Using your contrived example, it's pretty hard to understand what you're actually trying to do. Could you perhaps explain it with a little more context or maybe without foo/bar, but with real examples?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can create dynamically variables using the `$$` notation:

```php
$variable = "email_$name";
$$variable = "something";
```

However I'm not sure of what you're trying to do

1. What's the point of computing `$email_something` if it can be easily computed from something?
2. Why do you create those variables instead of just storing this in an array?